# Making a new map

Tags: python, pygame

Today I took a crack at making a little platformer in pygame. I used a lot of code from a very nifty and helpful tutorial, because I didn't know exactly how to do it.

So far, a map is made by processing a 32x32 portion of the screen and assigning it a block type, based on the character in the map text portion. So far I have a platform block, a border block, and an exit block that I want to eventually make the game load a new level.

My question is: If I "beat the level" and want to make the game load a new map, how would I go about doing that? I've tried removing the sprites from the group, but I didn't have any luck. I've been trying for a while now and I'm getting a little bit discouraged.

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
import math
from pygame import *

DISPLAY = (800, 640)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    display.set_caption("Square2")
    timer = time.Clock()

    up = down = left = right = False
    bg = Surface((32,32))
    bg.convert()
    bg.fill(Color("#000000"))
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(32,32)
    platforms = []

    x = y = 0
    level = [
    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
    "P                       P",
    "P                       P",
    "P                       P",
    "P                       P",
    "P                       P",
    "P                       P",
    "P                       P",
    "P                       P",
    "P                       P",
    "P                       P",
    "P                       P",
    "P                   pp  P",
    "P                       P",
    "P                       P",
    "P           pppppp      P",
    "P                       P",
    "P  pppppp               P",
    "P                       P",
    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
            ]

    #builds the level
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col =="p":
                p = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(p)
                entities.add(p)
            if col == "E":
                e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                platforms.append(e)
                entities.add(e)
            if col == "P":
                P = Border(x, y)
                platforms.append(P)
                entities.add(P)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0
    entities.add(player)

    while 1:
        timer.tick(60)
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                #raise SystemExit, "ESCAPE"
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                #raise SystemExit, "ESCAPE"
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
                up = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True


            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
                up = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False

        #draw bg
        for y in range(20):
            for x in range(25):
                screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))

        #update player, draw everything else
        player.update(up, down, left, right, platforms)
        entities.draw(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(Color("#FF0000"))
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

        self.reset(150, 400)

    def reset(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.rect.center = (self.x, self.y)

    def update(self, up, down, left, right, platforms):
        if up:
            #only jump if on the ground
            if self.onGround:
                self.yvel = -8
        if down:
            pass
        if left:
            self.xvel = -5
        if right:
            self.xvel = 5
        if not self.onGround:
            #only accelerate wit gravity if in the air
            self.yvel +=0.3
            #max falling sapeed
            if self.yvel > 30:
                self.yvel = 30
        if not (left or right):
            self.xvel = 0

        # increment in x direction
        self.rect.left+= self.xvel
        # x-axis collisions
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0 , platforms)
        # increment in y direction
        self.rect.top +=self.yvel
        # assuming we're in the air
        self.onGround = False;
        # y-axis collisions
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    event.post(event.Event(QUIT))
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                if xvel < 0:
                        self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom
                    self.yvel = 0
                   # Player.rect.top =  Player.rect.top


class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(Color("#DDDDDD"))
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

        def update(self):
            pass

class Border(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill((0,0,0))
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

        def update(self):
            pass

class ExitBlock(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image.fill(Color("#0033FF"))



main()
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You're going about your game design wrong. Too much of your game is hard-coded. Add a `loadLevel` method.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to make a loadLevel method and to make it more "soft-coded." Thanks!

Comment: Also I notice that in your mainloop you have a _ton_ of if statements evaluating almost exactly the same thing. You could very easily create a dict `key_dict = {K_UP: False, K_DOWN: False, K_RIGHT: False, K_LEFT: False}` and rather than checking for each value do `if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key in key_dict: key_dict[e.key] = True`. Using these kinds of patterns will 1) reduce the amount of code you write and 2) make your code way more readable and easier to modify.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Oh, and I also modified the level loading and made it into its own separate method. It works!

Comment: You seem to have posted your entire code and said "it's not working". Perhaps you could create a sample script that attempts to only do exactly what you're trying to do that doesn't work as expected and post that? You said "I've tried removing the sprites from the group". Is that code still in there?

Comment: It's alright, I figured the problem out. And yes, if I could, I would have narrowed down the code and posted a sample, but the issue was that I didn't know exactly what was going wrong.

Comment: Good to hear. Would you please then either delete the question or provide an answer to it yourself? Right now, it looks like there is still a question to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Create an algorithm to randomly create a viable level and output a readable string for a level. Automatically line it with borders, make a few randomized platforms, and the exit on the platform furthest from the player. You could even calculate if a jump from one platform to the next is possible, which you probably should do. To load your level in, just re-call main(). Also, entity seems like it is just a wrapper for sprite, you may want to keep it, but it seems like it's just taking up space. Because the algorithm would probably be the biggest piece of your entire program, I won't write an example, but if your looking for a way to load in a new level or a place to start on the algorithm this should work.